# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'None' to data type int.DB-Lib

Tags: python, database, dataframe

I tried to import a python dataframe into database on SQL server. I got an error like this:

```
    $ python mssql_insert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 448, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1064, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1095, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1228, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1639, in _mssql.check_cancel_and_raise
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1683, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (245, b"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'None' to data type int.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XZHANGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\Users\XZHANGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql.OperationalError: (245, b"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'None' to data type int.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

It mentioned can't import "None" value into SQL database (I remember it can definitely do).

Can someone find the problem here?